# shut down local client of hazelcast exector service

Tags: executorservice, hazelcast, shutdown, executor

We are using a hazelcast executor service to distribute tasks across our cluster of servers.

We want to shut down one of our servers and take it out of the cluster but allow it to continue working for a period to finish what it is doing but not accept any new tasks from the hazelcast executor service.

I don't want to shut down the hazelcast instance because the current tasks may need it to complete their work.

Shutting down the hazelcast executor service is not what I want. That shuts down the executor cluster-wide.

I would like to continue processing the tasks in the local queue until it is empty and then shut down.

Is there a way for me to let a node in the cluster continue to use hazelcast but tell it to stop accepting new tasks from the executor service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that easily, however you have member attributes (Member::setX/::getX) and you could set an attribute to signal "no new tasks please" and when you submit a tasks you either preselect a member to execute on based on the attribute or you use the overload with the MemberSelector.

Comment: This is a nice hint. Thanks! This seems a shortcoming in hazelcast. I would that the parent task not have to be involved in deciding where a task can execute. However, I think I can make something work with this hint.

My thought is to use public  submit(Callable<T> task, MemberSelector memberSelector) and have the member selector return all tasks that do not have an attribute of "shutting down". The executor will pick one of these at random and send the task there.

Thanks!

Comment: here is what I am trying:  first, when i know we want to shut down a server we run this:  `getInstance().getCluster().getLocalMember().setBooleanAttribute(HAZELCAST_SHUTDOWN_KEY, true)`   Then in our task runner we do this:
`
        MemberSelector memberSelector = new MemberSelector() {
            @Override
            public boolean select(Member member) {
                return !member.getBooleanAttribute(HazelcastService.HAZELCAST_SHUTDOWN_KEY);
            }
        };
        return _executor.submit(task, memberSelector);

`
I'll post back if there are any issues.